# Abelianization of subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, abelian-groups

Consider the following subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$

$$H_G = \{A\in GL(n,\mathbb{C})\: | \: AA^t = \lambda_AI, \text{for some } \lambda_A\in\mathbb{C}^{*}\}\subset GL(n,\mathbb{C})$$

$$H_S = \{A\in SL(n,\mathbb{C})\: | \: AA^t = \lambda_AI, \text{for some } \lambda_A\in\mathbb{C}^{*}\}\subset SL(n,\mathbb{C})$$

Note that $H_S = H_G\cap SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and that for $H_S$ the complex numbers $\lambda_A$ are $n$-th roots of unity.

So we have a morphism $H_S\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ mapping $A\mapsto \lambda_A$. The abelianization of $H_S$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand, the determinant gives a morphism $H_G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}$. So on this side it seems that the abelianization of $H_G$ is $\mathbb{C}^{*}$.

Note that $GL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_G\cong SL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_S$. In particualr, the character groups of $H_G$ and $H_S$ should coincide. But this is not the case for what I said before. One of them is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the other one $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

I wanted to ask you if someone can see what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you say that the character group of $H_G$ and $H_S$ should coincide ? And finding an homomorphism $\chi:G\to \Bbb{C}^*$ doesn't mean that $G^{ab}\cong \chi(G)$

Comment: These character groups are the Picard groups of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_G$ and $SL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_S$ which are isomorphic. Yes, I know that $G^{ab}$ could be a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ but in this case I can not see how. But you are right, probably the mistake is there.

Comment: But then why is the character group of $H_G/SO(n,\mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

There are two homomorphisms $H_G\to\mathbf{C}^*$, namely $\delta=\det|_{H_G}$ and $\lambda$, and $H_S=\operatorname{Ker}\delta$. First consider $f=\delta\times\lambda: H_G\to\mathbf{C}^*\times\mathbf{C}^*$.

By definition, the kernel of $f$ (which is also the kernel of $\lambda|_{H_S}$) is $\mathrm{SO}(n,\mathbf{C})$. This is known to be a perfect group for every $n$. It follows that $f:H_G\to f(H_G)$ and $\lambda:H_S\to\lambda(H_S)$ are the abelianization homomorphism.

It remains to determine these images. For $n=0$ all groups are trivial, so assume $n\ge 1$.

Then in restriction to $\mathbf{C}^*I_n$, both $\delta$ and $\lambda$ are surjective, given by $\delta(tI_n)=t^n$ and $\lambda(tI_n)=t^2$. Hence, if $(u,v)$ belongs to $f(H_G)$, and $v=w^2$, then $(uw^{-n},1)$ belongs to the image as well, i.e., is the determinant of some orthogonal matrix, which forces $uw^{-n}=\pm 1$, i.e., $u^2=v^n$.

Conversely, if $u^2=v^n$, consider the scalar matrix $wI_n$. Then $f(wI_n)=(w^n,w^2)$. If $w^n=u$, then this equals $(u,v)$ and we are done. Otherwise, $w^n=-u$. Then pick a matrix $M$ in $\mathrm{O}(n)\smallsetminus\mathrm{SO}(n)$: then $f(wM)=(u,v)$.

Hence the image of $f$ is $\{(u,v)\in\mathbf{C}^*\times\mathbf{C}^*:u^2=v^n\}$. If $n=2m$ is even, this is the same as $\{(u,v)\in\mathbf{C}^*\times\mathbf{C}^*:u=\pm v^m\}$ isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}^*\times C_2$ ($C_2$ cyclic of order $2$ generated by $(-1,1)$ and the identity component being $\{u=v^m\}$. If $n=2m+1$ is odd, this abelianization is isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}^*$, parameterized as $\{(w^n,w^2):w\in\mathbf{C}^*\}$ (where $w=uv^{-m}$).

If we restrict to determinant 1, the condition $u^2=v^n$ becomes $u=1$, $v^n=1$. So the image of the abelianization $\lambda:H_S\to\mathbf{C}^*$ is just the group $\mu_n$ of $n$-roots of unity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The thing that is confusing me is the following. The quotients $GL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_G$ and $SL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_S$ are isomorphic (unless I am missing something here). So their Picard groups are isomorphic. These Picard groups are the character groups of the abelianizations of $H_G$ and $H_S$ which by your description turn out to be different.

Comment: @JimRoss Isomorphic as what? these are not normal subgroups, so these quotients are not groups. Maybe you mean that the canonical map $S/H_S\to G/H_G$ is a bijection, which is correct, this is even an isomorphism of varieties. I'm not aware of results relating the Picard group of homogeneous spaces to abelianizations.

Comment: Exactly, I meant isomorphic as algebraic varieties. In general, if $G$ is a connected affine algebraic group and $H\subset G$ a closed subgroup there is an isomorphism $\chi(H)\rightarrow Pic_G(G/H)$, where $\chi(H)$ is the character group of $H$ and $Pic_G(G/H)$ is the group of equivariant isomorphism classes of $G$-linearized line bundles on $G/H$. Denote by $\mathcal{X}_G(H)$ the subgroup of $\chi(H)$ of characters extending to characters of $G$. If $Pic(G)  = 0$ then there is an exact sequence $$0\mapsto\chi_G(H)\rightarrow\chi(H)\rightarrow Pic_G(G/H)\rightarrow Pic(G/H)\mapsto 0$$

Comment: If $Pic(G) = 0$ and $\chi(G) = 0$ then $\chi(H)$ is isomorphic to $Pic(G/H)$. Then, the problem could be that $Pic(GL(n,\mathbb{C}))$ is not trivial while $Pic(SL(n,\mathbb{C}))$ is trivial.

Comment: I meant that the problem could be that $\chi(GL(n,\mathbb{C}))$ is not trivial while $\chi(SL(n,\mathbb{C}))$ is trivial. However, when $n$ is odd then $\chi(H_G) = \mathbb{C}^{*}$, and since $\chi(GL(n,\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^{*}$ we have $\chi_G(H) = \chi(H)$ in the above exact sequence.

Comment: (Not important, but your $\mapsto$ should be $\to$ in the exact sequence)

Comment: Are you saying that there are two natural maps $\chi(H)\to Pic_G(G/H)$, one of which is an isomorphism, the other one lying in this exact sequence? I'm confused.

Comment: In the above exact sequence the second map is an isomorphism so the image of the first one is zero but since the first one is injective this implies that $\chi_G(H)$ must be trivial.

Comment: No, the one lying in the exact sequence is the isomorphism. This is the thing that is bothering me. I do not see how the sequence could hold if $\chi_G(H)$ is not trivial.

Comment: Well, if you have an isomorphism in an exact sequence, it means that both neighboring maps are zero...

Comment: That's it. Anyway, I found this result in Theorem 4.5.1.2 of this book: https://books.google.it/books?id=Tl03BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=Cox+Rings+laface+hausen+Theorem+4.5.1.2.&source=bl&ots=wtDuDZDXOv&sig=ACfU3U1Mf5muuiZEZbFySMPFxQZnPjBKpw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqvLuZjdPtAhUEzaQKHSAYDq8Q6AEwBXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=Cox%20Rings%20laface%20hausen%20Theorem%204.5.1.2.&f=false

Comment: There must be a mistake.

Comment: I think the isomorphism in the exact sequence means that we can read the group in the middle either as $\chi(H)$ or as $Pic_G(G/H)$. So it would read: $$0\rightarrow \chi_G(H)\rightarrow\chi(G)\rightarrow Pic(G/H)\rightarrow 0$$ However, for $n$ odd we still have that $\chi_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}(H_G)\cong \chi(GL(n,\mathbb{C}))\cong \mathbb{C}^{*}$. So $Pic(GL(n,\mathbb{C})/H_G)$ should be trivial but we know it is not.

Comment: (again the left and right arrows are $\to$, not $\mapsto$)